# iphone app flow diagram map for the bigger picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been teaching myself iPhone development for a few months now (actually more than a few!!), when I realised that the information I was getting from text books wasn't sticking and is swimming around in my brain like object soup.

I understand bits and pieces, but for the most part can never grasp the bigger picture and connections that need to be made. So I thought I would try and put the bigger picture into a flow diagram. So I sat down and without using any text books put together a flow diagram of the bigger picture to how an iPhone app works, well how I see that it works.

Would be good if anyone could take a look, see what you think, correct mistakes, contribute to make it better or even tell me that if for works for me great, but actually it wont make sense to anyone else!

Take a look at the flow diagram so far here.
http://theknowledgeoflondon.com/Iphoneflowchart.pdf

Email me if you have any further ideas - design@securitieslendingtimes.com

Thanks, Laff

ps - What would people agree to be the definitive iPhone development text. I think I have learnt that some explain things better than others and that there isn't one good book that does what it says on the tin!

Comment: In all honesty, I find the diagram more confusing than reading the explanations in a book.  But everyone is different in terms of learning and it could potentially help someone out there.